# need an iframe to refresh automatically

Tags: javascript, iframe, refresh

I have a situation where I need to refresh an iframe about every 30 seconds. I have looked through the forums and tried a few things, to no avail.

```
<iframe id="Doyle" src="http://www.dot.ca.gov/dist2/rwis/sm_doyle.php" 
width="375" height="560">
</iframe>

<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["Doyle"].location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: What have you done to determine the root cause? Are you seeing any error output in the browser console? Have you checked to see if the `reloadIFrame` function is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code

```
<iframe id="Doyle" src="http://www.dot.ca.gov/dist2/rwis/sm_doyle.php" 
width="375" height="560">
</iframe>

<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 var frameHolder=document.getElementById('Doyle');
frameHolder.src="http://www.dot.ca.gov/dist2/rwis/sm_doyle.php"
}
</script>
```

check working example below

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mre0AgMjh5o7wXl5YvVP?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

an iframe is an element, it is not an object like the window one, and to change its target you just need to update its src attribute, `document.getElementById('YOURFRAMEID').src="http://google.com/";` or something like that

Credits here [Change URL in an iframe using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036572/change-url-in-an-iframe-using-javascript)